# what do you call a donut-shaped meter like UI element like this?

Tags: user-interface, frontend

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I was wondering what this UI element is called. Do you just call it a donut chart ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's literally called a donut but usually not when it has a little arrow underneath. I think donut is usually for meters which fill the arch with color(s). With the arrow present, I'd call it a gauge.